# Can I undo actions after I saved the context in core data?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsundomanager

I have a common Core Data app for iOS. Every time something is changed, I call save from the NSManagedContext, so all changes are moved to the database.

As far as I understand, I can only undo changes from the managed context, but not from database. Am I right?

What I want is commit all changes immediately to the database and be able to undo the las action. Is that possible?

The only option I see, is not committing the last change, that is, leave the last change in the NSManagedContext, so I can undo that change. But this idea has a problem, if the program crashes or user makes a backup (using iTunes or iCloud), then this last change will disappear. Do you agree with me? How can I have my data always committed in the database and at the same time have the possibility to undo the last change? As far as I understand, that's not possible using Core Data. I hope I'm wrong.

Well, I would like to know your opinions about this. Thanks.